# Push Notification in Web Server

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, java-9, http2

I just have a quick question.

Is it possible to send a push notification upon receiving a request in the web server?

- For example, user A sends a message to user B
- user A's request goes to the web server (Tomcat in this case)

Upon receiving request from user A, the server sends request to APNs to send notification to user B (user B's token has been retrieved earlier).

I am trying to use jdk9.incubator.http to send a push notification to the user B's device in doPost() method when user A sends a request to the web server.

My class extends HttpServlet
`public class AuthenticationController extends HttpServlet`

Trying to send push notification upon authenticating the user

```
@SuppressWarnings("exports")
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
    try {
        LOGGER.debug("POST requested from a client");
        Authenticate(req, resp);
        sendNotification();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Oops",e);
    }
}
```

Please give me advice to do it correctly.

---

EDIT:

I learned that the socket closes after the response is flushed in HttpServlet, so I tried to send another request to send a notification before flushing the response.

```
private void sendResponse(
        HttpServletResponse resp, Gson gson ,Object obj) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    sendTestRequest()
    resp.getOutputStream().print(gson.toJson(obj));
    resp.getOutputStream().flush();
}//sendResponse()
```

I tested out JDK9.incubator in the main thread of another project that I worked on, which worked beautifully; however, I cannot somehow have it work in my tomcat server environment.

When I tried to send a simple request to just test out jdk9.incubator.request, nothing happens. sendTestRequest() method simply sends out a http request. Example can be shown [here](https://labs.consol.de/development/2017/03/14/getting-started-with-java9-httpclient.html).

Below code snippet is an example of what my http/2 request looks like

```
final HttpRequest request = setHttpRequest(notification);
    NotificationResponse resp = new NotificationResponse(null);
    try {
        HttpResponse<String> response = 
                getHttpClient().send(request, BodyHandler.asString());
        resp.setResult(response.statusCode(), response.body());

        if (resp.isAccepted()) {
            System.out.println("Push Notification was accepted by APNs");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request rejected reason: " + resp.getFailureReason());
        }
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Exception was thrown; check the log");
        LOGGER.fatal("Failed to send request synchronously", e);
    }
```

Comment: Is this a push notification to a random mobile device that user B happens to be on, or to the browser from where B currently has a session open?

Comment: It is to a random mobile device that user B happens to be on. In fact, I am trying to use HttpServlet to accomplish this. I will add some more codes now.

Comment: Take a look at a [websocket example](https://benas.github.io/2016/02/21/using-the-java-api-for-webSocket-to-create-a-chat-server.html) - it's going to be tough using even the newer servlet stuff directly.

Comment: If it's generic push, rather look at the api you're intending to call, rather then where to call it from.

Comment: @stdunbar I have never used web socket before. Looks like it would be very fun; however, I do not want to use web socket because it has to be kept open. I am trying to use Push Notification with servlet so that I do not have to do any of server exhausting practices, such as long polling, web socket, etc.

Comment: @OlafKock can you clarify on taking a look at the api? Are you saying that another project that I created for push notification is breaking down? I am using this Notice project in my web project by importing it as a jar file. Everything was working fine when I ran tests before making it a jar file.